# Why are users seeing edit pages outside of Admin UI

Tags: 7, theming

I just tested the editorial process for authors on our new web site.  For some reason, although admins and editors see pages in the normal Admin UI (using the *Seven* theme) when editing a page, members of the author role see it in the public UI that displays for non-logged-in users browsing the web site.

At `/admin/appearance` I have **Administration theme** set to *Seven*, and I have 'Use the administration theme when editing or creating content' checked.  [image]

Why would this setting take effect for admins and editors, but not authors?

Answer (score 2):

D'oh.  I somehow missed this before in the permissions:

`View the administration theme`

Admins and editors had this permission enabled, but authors did not.  Enabling it for authors fixed things.